# DB2 SQL, Calculate total on orders ready to ship

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to calculate the total value or all orders where we have all items in stock required to fill the order.  In the example below, I want to select only the total value of order 100 only, since there is not enough inventory to fill order 200.

```
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
| Order | Item | Qty Ordered | Qty In Stock | Price |
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|  100  |   A  |     10      |     25       |  1.00 |
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|  100  |   B  |     15      |     50       |  2.00 |
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|  100  |   C  |     30      |     75       |  3.00 |
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|  200  |   A  |      5      |     25       |  1.00 |
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|  200  |   B  |    100      |     50       |  2.00 | * Not enough stock to fill
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|  200  |   C  |     35      |     75       |  3.00 |
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Almost impossible because of your design flaw -- "Qty In Stock" is really "quantity in stock at the time of order was placed" and worse there are multiple versions of the amount throughout the table. Stock really nees to be in a separate table from orders.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Think of it as a view not a design flaw.  Its actually a nice looking question.

Comment: If he had another order of 20 for product A in the table it would pass the test giving a total of 35 against a stock of 25. He really needs a separate "stock" table and to check each order individually. What he wants cannot be done in a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select o.id, sum(o.qty_ordered * o.price) as total_value
  from orders o
  where o.id not in (
    select id from orders where qty_ordered > qty_in_stock
  )
  group by o.id
```

Comment: Thank you! this is was exactly what I needed